# Access denied for application with client credentials flow

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

We have set up an application in AAD.

The application has been granted access to read/write all messages/mails and "read users profiles" and a global admin have pushed the "Grant permissions" button in the portal.
Still We get `Access denied` error when trying to access

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{myId}/MailFolders/Inbox/ChildFolders
```

for my userid (`myId`). The URL works fine in graph explorer when I'm logged in as my own user.

Also, decoding the JWT at jwt.io shows the application id, name and "aud" (https://graph.microsoft.com) - but no roles/scopes.

What have we done wrong?

Comment: which scopes did you ask? you'd need to request `https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. See https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Client-credential-flows#scopes-to-request

Comment: Scope is set to https://graph.microsoft.com/.default

Answer (score 0):

These are delegated permissions... so you will need a user with the same rights and use the credentials of the user in your authorization flow for your app.

[The effective rights are the intersection of the user rights and and the rigths of the app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent).

"Effective permissions are the permissions that your app will have when making requests to an API.

- For delegated permissions, the effective permissions of your app will be the least privileged intersection of the delegated permissions the app has been granted (through consent) and the privileges of the currently signed-in user. Your app can never have more privileges than the signed-in user."

The user also needs permission to use the app in AAD.

If it is not a delegated permission, maybe there is the need for some global admin to grant the consent for all users. "Topic Admins" can only "request" the permissions for the app and the global admin can consent for all users.

[image]

Comment: The app has no delegated permissions. The permissions mentioned are added as application permissions and it is using the client credentials flow described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow

Comment: which rigth is this? "granted access to read/write all messages/mails"
I guess it is from "Office 365 Exchange"?

Comment: It is Mail.ReadWrite.All from Microsoft Graph. It is indeed related to exchange online (office 365)

Comment: Checked again, and the permission itself is a delegated permission, in Graph as well as in Exchange. So you will need a user, who has the rights as well and use user credentials for authorization.

Comment: Andreas I truly appreciate you taking the time to try and help me out but please read my question and comments again. The permission to read/write ALL mailboxes is an application permission that requires global admin consent (which is already granted). I bet you can't find that permission under delegated permissions only read/write for a single user... Also as I said before everything is setup correctly according to the documentation in my first comment. BTW. As mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/53204331/998791 the problem solved itself somehow so my setup was correct from the beginning

Comment: The weird thing is, that I find those rights ONLY as delegated permissions. 

Comment: According to the screenshot in your answer the permissions related to mail under "Delegated" is "Read and write user and shared mail", which is not the same as "Read and write all mail" :)

Comment: I believe you, I am just unable to find the same permisson.

Comment: Weird. Perhaps you need Application administrator privileges? Any way here is a screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/8aHyDmm.png

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I submitted a ticket to Microsoft Support. I haven't received any response yet, but now it all works just fine. I have no idea why, but when I was submitting the ticket this morning a warning was shown that an outage in Azure AD was recently fixed so maybe that is why things didn't work yesterday.